# How to get total number of hours in a year using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want to get the Total numbers of hours in a year using VB.Net. Is there any method or function which can help us achieve that?

I want to get something like:

```
Private Function GetTotalHours(ByVal year As String) As String
    Dim time As String = String.Empty
    Try
         ' Calculate here...

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try        
    Return time
End Function
```

And use it like:

```
TextBox1.Text = GetTotalHours('2008')   ' Result will be = 8784
TextBox1.Text = GetTotalHours('2013')   ' Result will be = 8760
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this:

```
Public Function GetTotalHours(ByVal year As Integer) As Integer
    Dim dtAux As New Date(year, 1, 1)
    Dim ts As TimeSpan = dtAux.AddYears(1) - dtAux

    Return CInt(ts.TotalHours)
End Function
```

Comment: [TotalHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx) is double. Don't we need to convert it into Integer??

Comment: @Palash Completely true. Edited